# When I parameterize a function, what happens to its dimensionality? Specifically, in the context of the implicit function theorem.

Tags: functions

Suppose I have some functions $f,g$ such that 
$$f:\Bbb{R} \mapsto \Bbb{R}^2$$
$$g:\Bbb{R}^2 \mapsto \Bbb{R}^n$$

**My Question:**

For some $c \in \Bbb{R}$, is $g(f(c))$ a function of one variable? If so, why is the fact $g$ requires two arguments irrelevant?

EDIT:

Specifically, I am considering a function 
$$\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{y}) = \nabla f(\mathbf{x}) -\nabla (\lambda g(\mathbf{x}))$$
where $$\mathbf{y} = [\lambda,\mathbf{x}]$$ 
I want to write 
$$\mathbf{F}(c,\mathbf{y}) = 0$$
and use the implicit function theorem to show that $\lambda$ and $\mathbf{x}$ can be parametrized by $c$, but I am confused why/if I can write $\mathbf{F}$ in terms of $c$ and $\mathbf{y}$ given that the first derivative of my Lagrangian multiplier equation isn't a function of $c$.

Comment: $g \circ f$ is a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$. End of story.

Comment: For a $c\in\mathbb R$, the expression $g(f(c))$ is a real number, so the way you phrase your question is suspect. However, a function that sends $c$ to $g(f(c))$ is indeed a function of one variable, since you plug in one number $c$. I don't know what you mean by "irrelevant" if your question.

Comment: @LevBorisov: It isn't a real number, it is a tuple of $n$ real numbers

Comment: You have $f(x)=(f_{1}(x),f_{2}(x))$ and $g(x,y)=(g_{1}(x,y),g_{2}(x,y),\dots, g_{n}(x,y))$. Then $g(f(c)) = g(f_{1}(c),f_{1}(c))=(g_{1}(f(c)),g_{2}(f(c)),\dots, g_{n}(f(c)))$. Edit: To your edited post, what is your $\mathbf{x}$ defined for?

Comment: @MPW Yes, indeed, an n-tuple of real numbers (still not a function :)

Comment: The difficulty here seems largely one of notation.  The posed question involves a composition of functions, written as $g(f(c))$, so that the inner function $f(c)$ provides both arguments for $g$ presumably, and conceptually both left and right "return values" of $f$ are made to depend only on the "input value" $c$.  It is then unclear how your desired application would conform to that notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that $f(c)$ is a pair of values because of the range you specified. Maybe think of it like $(f_1(c),f_2(c))$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $g(f(c)$ is a function of one variable.

The fact that $g$ requires two arguments is **not** irrelevant; it has to match the fact that $f$ provides a result in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and thus "provides two arguments." If $g$ were a function from $\Bbb{R}^3 \mapsto  \Bbb{R}$, for instance, then with this $f$,  $g(f(c)$ would be meaningless.